# "A lot of" or "lots of"

Tags: formality

I was wondering which one of the following sentences is most appropriate:

1. I have been provided with a lot of information.
2. I have been provided with lots of information.

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct.

I personally find "lots" to be more informal than "a lot," but both are on the informal side. They can be used (more or less) interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestions on how to make it more formal?

Comment: Actually, in this case, I find "a lot" to be formal enough for any use really. In other sentences, "many" is usually more formal than "a lot," but since you can't have "many information," I think that "a lot of information" is a good way to go.

Comment: Other more formal alternatives: "a great deal of <x>", "copious <x>", "a large amount of <x>", "vast quantities of <x>", "an abundance of <x>"…

Comment: For non-count nouns like "information", you can use *much*, as in "much information".

Answer (score 0):

I'm no native Englishman, but I always had felt that "a lot" implies plural (like in "parking lot" vs. "parking slot"), so using "lots of" really makes no sense.